# Acumatica - POOrder_RowSelected override enabling field when Status is Pending approval

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to enable a certain field when POOrder status is on "Pending Approval" like Description field but when I override it on POOrder_RowSelected event it still doesn't enable the field.

```
protected void POOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
            InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);

        POOrder row = (POOrder)e.Row;
        if (row != null)
        {
            if (row.Hold == false && row.Status == POOrderStatus.Balanced) // Balance is indicated on Pending appoval
            {
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<POOrder.orderDesc>(cache, row, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using Automation Steps.

Select your Purchase Order screen, and on Step ID select "NL Pending Approval". (See below)

Then locate "Purchase Order" TableName with FieldName "*" and unchecked the Disabled box. Then Save your changes.

[image]

Then you can extend the POOrderEntry graph and on RowSelected event handler add your custom logic(and set enable the desired fields):

```
public void POOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
           InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);

        POOrder order= (POOrder)e.Row;
        if (order == null || Base.IsExport) return;

        if (order.Status == POOrderStatus.Balanced)
        {
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<POLine.orderDesc>(sender, order, true);
        }
    }
```

Sample above would enable Description field when POOrder is with Balanced Status. Here is another link to similar question involving Custom User Fields: [How to enable a custom field on PO301000 when the PO is in Open status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287944/how-to-enable-a-custom-field-on-po301000-when-the-po-is-in-open-status)